# Derive new int field from an existing string field - MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection of documents like the following:

```
[
  {
    "_id" : NUUID("51611712-b966-4562-8937-06015a6691ec"),
    "Name":"NM-1",
    "DateCreated" : ISODate("2019-07-29T11:33:19.090Z"),
    "DateModified" : ISODate("2019-12-23T08:08:40.339Z"),
    "IsDeleted" : false,
  },
  {
    "_id" : NUUID("51611712-b966-4562-8937-06015a6691ec"),
    "Name":"NM-02",
    "DateCreated" : ISODate("2019-07-29T11:33:19.090Z"),
    "DateModified" : ISODate("2019-12-23T08:08:40.339Z"),
    "IsDeleted" : false,
  },
  {
    "_id" : NUUID("51611712-b966-4562-8937-06015a6691ec"),
    "Name":"NM-095",
    "DateCreated" : ISODate("2019-07-29T11:33:19.090Z"),
    "DateModified" : ISODate("2019-12-23T08:08:40.339Z"),
    "IsDeleted" : false,
  },
  {
    "_id" : NUUID("51611712-b966-4562-8937-06015a6691ec"),
    "Name":"NM-0096",
    "DateCreated" : ISODate("2019-07-29T11:33:19.090Z"),
    "DateModified" : ISODate("2019-12-23T08:08:40.339Z"),
    "IsDeleted" : false,
  },
  {
    "_id" : NUUID("51611712-b966-4562-8937-06015a6691ec"),
    "Name":"NM-105",
    "DateCreated" : ISODate("2019-07-29T11:33:19.090Z"),
    "DateModified" : ISODate("2019-12-23T08:08:40.339Z"),
    "IsDeleted" : false,
  },
  {
    "_id" : NUUID("51611712-b966-4562-8937-06015a6691ec"),
    "Name":"NM-0106",
    "DateCreated" : ISODate("2019-07-29T11:33:19.090Z"),
    "DateModified" : ISODate("2019-12-23T08:08:40.339Z"),
    "IsDeleted" : false,
  },
  {
    "_id" : NUUID("51611712-b966-4562-8937-06015a6691ec"),
    "Name":"NM-000109",
    "DateCreated" : ISODate("2019-07-29T11:33:19.090Z"),
    "DateModified" : ISODate("2019-12-23T08:08:40.339Z"),
    "IsDeleted" : false,
  },
  ...
]
```

I want to add a new field to the documents - `Number` if it not exists. The `Number` field will be equal to number in field `Name` without the `NM-` and pre-zeros.

For example after processing:

```
[
  {
    "_id" : NUUID("51611712-b966-4562-8937-06015a6691ec"),
    "Name":"NM-1",
    "Number": 1,
    "DateCreated" : ISODate("2019-07-29T11:33:19.090Z"),
    "DateModified" : ISODate("2019-12-23T08:08:40.339Z"),
    "IsDeleted" : false,
  },
  {
    "_id" : NUUID("51611712-b966-4562-8937-06015a6691ec"),
    "Name":"NM-02",
    "Number": 2,
    "DateCreated" : ISODate("2019-07-29T11:33:19.090Z"),
    "DateModified" : ISODate("2019-12-23T08:08:40.339Z"),
    "IsDeleted" : false,
  },
  {
    "_id" : NUUID("51611712-b966-4562-8937-06015a6691ec"),
    "Name":"NM-095",
    "Number": 95,
    "DateCreated" : ISODate("2019-07-29T11:33:19.090Z"),
    "DateModified" : ISODate("2019-12-23T08:08:40.339Z"),
    "IsDeleted" : false,
  },
  {
    "_id" : NUUID("51611712-b966-4562-8937-06015a6691ec"),
    "Name":"NM-0096",
    "Number": 96,
    "DateCreated" : ISODate("2019-07-29T11:33:19.090Z"),
    "DateModified" : ISODate("2019-12-23T08:08:40.339Z"),
    "IsDeleted" : false,
  },
  {
    "_id" : NUUID("51611712-b966-4562-8937-06015a6691ec"),
    "Name":"NM-105",
    "Number": 105,
    "DateCreated" : ISODate("2019-07-29T11:33:19.090Z"),
    "DateModified" : ISODate("2019-12-23T08:08:40.339Z"),
    "IsDeleted" : false,
  },
  {
    "_id" : NUUID("51611712-b966-4562-8937-06015a6691ec"),
    "Name":"NM-0106",
    "Number": 106,
    "DateCreated" : ISODate("2019-07-29T11:33:19.090Z"),
    "DateModified" : ISODate("2019-12-23T08:08:40.339Z"),
    "IsDeleted" : false,
  },
  {
    "_id" : NUUID("51611712-b966-4562-8937-06015a6691ec"),
    "Name":"NM-000109",
    "Number": 109,
    "DateCreated" : ISODate("2019-07-29T11:33:19.090Z"),
    "DateModified" : ISODate("2019-12-23T08:08:40.339Z"),
    "IsDeleted" : false,
  },
  ...
]
```

How to write MongoDB script for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Aggregation Pipeline we can get the desired result

Pipeline stages - [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) and [$out](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) are required

Pipeline operators - [$substr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/substr/) and [$toInt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toInt/) are required

Query to get the result

```
db.collection_name.aggregate([
    { $project: { 
        "Name":1, 
        "DateCreated" : 1, 
        "DateModified" : 1, 
        "IsDeleted" : 1,
        "Number" : {
             $toInt : { $substr : ["$Name", 3, -1] } 
           } 
       } 
    },
    {$out: "collection_name"}
  ]);
```

Please note:

In substring operation we are starting from 3 and ending with -1(if length is given as negative number then mongo will process the rest of the string from the starting point), since we are starting from 3, this query will work if all the `Name` in the collection are having the prefix `NM-`.

We are using $out to rewrite the entire collection with the added Number attribute

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB 4.2+ has **Aggregation Pipeline Operators** that may work for you.

```
db.collection.<update method>(
    {},
    [
        {"$set": {"newIntField": { $toInt: "$Name" }}}
    ]
)
```

Checkout [the docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toInt/) for more details

Comment: The Name field has String values NM- prefixed, so the Name field cannot be converted as number, first we need to use substring to split the number part and the prefix part, and then we can use $toInt